# How to create dynamically a matrix ANDROID DEVELOPMENT

Tags: android, matrix, dynamic, rows

I am new in android development. I have a question. 
Is there possible to create a layout dynamically, to draw a matrix ( edit texts), where the user can input the elements, and later i can reference to this elements, with there "positions"? I want to scan a user inputted matrix, which i would like to make operations(on the rows, columns and Matrix[x][y]th elements), and show it the user again.
Where should i start to search?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start reading about layouts and views. Specifically, `LinearLayout` (how they can be horizontal and vertical), and `EditText`, which is your basic text input control.

If you have little knowledge about GUI systems, Java, or programming in general (as opposed to being new to Android while experienced in, say, Windows or iOS), that would be your first stop.